# DISTINCT только одного столбца для выборки всех столбцов таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, фильтрация

Есть таблица:

```
id  type    script date                     name    status  priority    

6   3       link    Пт 10.04.20 16:38:48    name    1       1
7   2       link    Пт 10.04.20 16:38:48    name    1       1,2
8   1       link    Пт 10.04.20 16:38:48    name    1       1,2
9   2       link    Пт 10.04.20 16:38:48    name    1       1,2
```

Если сделать так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `type` FROM `api_script` WHERE `status` = 1
```

То всё получается правильно:

```
type

3
2
1
```

Но, если выбрать все столбцы, то не работает. Как я понял, `DISTINCT` работает сразу со всеми столбцами.

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы он работал только с первым столбцом?
Если нет, тогда какие варианты?

Желаемый результат:

```
id  type    script date                     name    status  priority    

6   3       link    Пт 10.04.20 16:38:48    name    1       1
7   2       link    Пт 10.04.20 16:38:48    name    1       1,2
8   1       link    Пт 10.04.20 16:38:48    name    1       1,2
```

Comment: `Но, если выбрать все поля,` - а что вы хотите получить тогда - всю таблицу?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос. Да, нужна вся таблица с уникальным полем `type`

Comment: то, что вы написали - group by (type)

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из комментариев:

> [1)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1108395/distinct-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b/1128848#comment1911375_1108395) то, что вы написали - group by (type) [2)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1108395/distinct-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b/1128848#comment1911379_1108395) Спасибо, работает

Да, работает, **но это только иллюзия**. Сегодня выведет для `type=2` - `id=7`, завтра - `id=9`.
Выберите критерий сортировки, например `id`. Если такого критерия нет, значит выводить все столбцы не надо, т.к. данные выбранные случайно - это мусор. Сделайте так (на [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec188b3e95b672050921e486900ce99c)):

```sql
with q (id, type, rest) as (
    select 6, 3, 'link    10.04.20 16:38:48    name    1       1   ' union all
    select 7, 2, 'link    10.04.20 16:38:48    name    1       1,2 ' union all
    select 8, 1, 'link    10.04.20 16:38:48    name    1       1,2 ' union all
    select 9, 2, 'link    10.04.20 16:38:48    name    1       1,2 ')
select id, type, rest from (
    select q.*, row_number() over (partition by type order by id asc) rn
    from q
) t
where rn=1
order by id;

id  type    rest
6   3       link    10.04.20 16:38:48    name    1       1   
7   2       link    10.04.20 16:38:48    name    1       1,2 
8   1       link    10.04.20 16:38:48    name    1       1,2
```